# Is there a 32 bit genymotion for ubuntu?

Tags: android-studio, genymotion, android-emulator

I have a 32 bit pc.  I would like to run android apps I have made in a fast android emulator.I heard genymotion is one of the fastest.But i dont know if it is available for a 32bit pc.

Are there any other good android emulators for my 32 bit pc?

Comment: Yes there is, you can follow this tutorial[GENYMOTION: FAST, EASY TO USE ANDROID (X86) EMULATOR WITH OPENGL HARDWARE ACCELERATION SUPPORT](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/genymotion-fast-easy-to-use-android-x86.html) note: Genymotion 2.7.0 and future versions will not be made available for 32-bit Linux operating systems. so you have to download an older version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They stopped supporting 32 bit versions.I contacted them and this is what they said:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, wanted genymotion for 32 bits

They stopped providing 32 bits version on release 2.7.0

I guess we will need to find a previous version but i can't find it anywhere, hope, already tried to contact them to ask about it, lets see if we get something, is a shame seems to be a decent emulator

https://www.genymotion.com/release-notes/

Genymotion 2.7.0 and future versions will not be made available for 32-bit Linux operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Genymotion as a 32bit application under Linux.

This works with this trick:

- If you installed Virtualbox on 32bit Windows, you can install the 32bit Windows version of Genymotion
- Now go to the order in which Virtualbox stores its VMs and copy the Genymotion folder into your Linux directory
- Then start Virtualbox for Linux, add a new machine and select the folder where you copied Genymotion before
- After minor adjustments, Genymotion should then run on Linux